# How can i define the size of my diagram? I have a different size

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, printing, size

I have two major questions:

First question: Why is the size of my diagram smaller than: width=10cm, height=15cm if i print it.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
%\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height=10cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar, grid=both, scale only axis=true,
  width=10cm, height=15cm]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{14mm}{5mm}},only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y color myvalue
2 3 1 100
4 3 2 3
2 7 3 0.75
7 7 4 45
8 5 2   3
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Second question: I want to have an x-axis and y-axis range from zero to ten with a step of 2. How does it work?

Comment: Does the printer do any scaling? Check the paper size of your PDF, you may get letter sized paper, and if you print on A4 and the printer automatically scales to fit, then the size will be reduced. Note also that it is better to have one specific question per thread, at least if the questions are very different, as in this case. (`xtick={0,2,...,10}`, similar for `ytick`. Axis limits are set with `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`, e.g.  `xmin=0`. These are all added to the `axis` options.)

Comment: thx it works :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by the printer rescaling the output.